# AlertDialog not to be blocking

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any possibility to pass any flag to AlertDialog so user can clicks on widgets on screen , not to be AlertDialog be blocking ?
When I show AlertDialog on screen I cannot click on anything bellow AlertDialog.

Comment: can you explain briefly?

Comment: If an AlertDialog is shown then it has the focus and you can't use any widget in the background.

Comment: An alert dialog is meant to block! Otherwise why should it be named `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog always run on main thread.It will block UI until you don't dismiss it.Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an answer to your actual question, but something else that may work for you:

Use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout as your outer layout (or encapsulate your layout in it) and define a second layout in the Frame/RelativeLayout, which will then lay on top of your actual layout.

You can configure it as normal (via setText() etc.) and use setVisibility() to show or hide it.

Answer (score 0):

See [setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29) in the docs.

> Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's
>   bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not
>   already set.
>
> Parameters:
>
> cancel    Whether the dialog should be canceled when touched outside the
>   window.

Otherwise, create your own dialog with the attributes you need.